# A list of linking CFNetwork version numbers to the version of iOS

Tags: ios4, cfnetwork

I'm wondering if anyone has a list of linking CFNetwork version numbers to the version of iOS?
I've found the list for [OSX CFNetwork versions](http://www.starcoder.com/wordpress/2008/02/cfnetwork-versions/) 
but it's quite old.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I made this list from some of the devices I had around at the time. It's not complete but hopefully it is helpful for someone else.

```
Device              OS       CFNetwork Version
iPod Touch 2G       3.1.3    CFNetwork/459 Darwin/10.0.0d3
iPod Touch 3G       4.0      CFNetwork/485.2 Darwin/10.3.1
iPhone 3GS          4.1      CFNetwork/485.10.2 Darwin/?
iPhone 3G           4.2.1    CFNetwork/485.12.7 Darwin/10.4.0
iPhone 4            4.3.2    CFNetwork/485.13.9 Darwin/?
iPod Touch 4G       4.3.5    CFNetwork/485.13.9 Darwin/11.0.0
iPhone 3GS          5.0      CFNetwork/548.0.3 Darwin/11.0.0
iPhone 4S           5.0.1    CFNetwork/548.0.4 Darwin/11.0.0
iPhone 4S           5.1      CFNetwork/548.1.4 Darwin/11.0.0
iPhone 4S           6.0-b3   CFNetwork/602 Darwin/13.0.0
iPhone 4S           6.0      CFNetwork/609 Darwin/13.0.0
iPhone 4S           6.1.2    CFNetwork/609.1.4 Darwin/13.0.0
iPad 3              7.1      CFNetwork/672.1.13 Darwin/14.0.0
```

Comment: Two more from server logs:
iPhone 4G-4.3.2-485.13.9; 
iPhone 3GS-4.1-485.10.2 ;

Comment: I have a few `CFNetwork/467.12` in my logs, as this is between 3.1.3 (459) and 4.0 (485.2) I'm working on the assumption it is 3.2 on the original iPad.

Comment: My original iPhone (v1) running OS v3.1.3 reports CFNetwork/459 Darwin/10.0.0d3 (like the iPod touch 2G above)

Comment: This list is useful, but the CFNetwork/Darwin numbers are reported by OS, and not by device. That is to say, an iPad running 6.1.2 will report the same numbers as the last row. While there are OS/device compatibility restrictions that make some combinations invalid, this list can be made more accurate by ignoring the first column.

Answer (score 0):

**iOS 6.1.3 iPad/iPod** - CFNetwork/609.1.4 Darwin/13.0.0

**iOS iPhoneiPad Simulator 6.1** - Desafio/1.5 CFNetwork/609.1.4 Darwin/12.3.0