# iPhone App OS Detection via User Agent

Tags: iphone, ios

In my awstats log (cpanel), the webservice consumed by the iphone app shows various user-agents like:

```
AppName/1.6 CFNetwork/485.13.9 Darwin/11.0.0
AppName/1.6 CFNetwork/548.0.3 Darwin/11.0.0
AppName/1.0 CFNetwork/485.13.9 Darwin/11.0.0
```

Is there a way to make sense of this? I am more interested in finding out the devices (iPhone, iPad etc.) and OSes (iOS4, iOS5 etc.) is that possible from this user agent?

Comment: Related (or even duplicate?): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239553/a-list-of-linking-cfnetwork-version-numbers-to-the-version-of-ios

Comment: Thanks but that is not updated. Is there any other link like that which is more current?

Comment: I guess you can't find out the device. I see `CFNetwork/485.13.9 Darwin/11.0.0` from 2 iPads with iOS 4.3.3 and 4.3.5, while the simulator with Xcode 4.2 on a MacBook says `CFNetwork/485.13.9 Darwin/10.8.0`.

Comment: You're probably best off setting the user-agent yourself to include the information you'd like. How are you making your request?

Comment: These requests are made at least by iOS HTML5 video player.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is not much info here. It turns out, it is in format :

```
AppName/AppVerson, CFNetwork/iOSVersion (4xx/5xx), Darwin/11.0.0
AppName/1.6 CFNetwork/485.13.9 Darwin/11.0.0
```

Comment: What does CFNetwork and Darwin mean or what are they a reference to?

Comment: @Erx_VB.NExT.Coder, 'Darwin' is the name of the underlying BSD system that powers OS X and iOS. CFNetwork ('Core Foundation Network') is basically the name of the networking framework iOS apps indirectly use when making HTTP requests.