# How can I read my application’s CFNetwork-level User-Agent?

Tags: ios, user-agent, cfnetwork

I want to programmatically retrieve my application’s `User-Agent` string. (Note: *not* the UA of a UIWebView in my application; the UA for `NSURLConnection`-based HTTP requests.)

There’s lots of guides on how to read an application's `UIWebView` `User-Agent`, but none on how to get at the `<appname>/1.0 CFNetwork/456.23` string that `CFNetwork` stuffs inside its HTTP requests. There’s API for `CFHTTPMessage` to copy out all header fields, but I only have an `NSURLRequest` and an `NSURLResponse`, and these are unbridged opaque types. Help!

(Some good background reading: [Changing the userAgent of NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532206/changing-the-useragent-of-nsurlconnection) mentions the format that I want to get at. [What HTTP User-Agent does my iOS program advertise itself as?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030550/what-http-user-agent-does-my-ios-program-advertise-itself-as) does as well.)

Comment: Instead of retrieving the header, could you just derive it from info in the bundle, UIDevice, and a table like the following? Of course, you'd need to complete the table, but there are a finite number of device/os combos that your app would care about... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239553/a-list-of-linking-cfnetwork-version-numbers-to-the-version-of-ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely twisted: create a local socket on port 80 and make a local request (to yourself), read the HTTP headers.

Comment: This is, no joke, one of the better solutions I’ve come up with thus far. This is just insane, right?